# Cannot edit Initiation Form of Designer Workflows with InfoPath

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I've got a reusable SP Designer workflow in SharePoint 2010, and I'm trying to edit the Initiation Form for it. I can open the workflow within SP Designer, click the form, and it opens in InfoPath. I then make the changes that I want, and try to Save/Publish it back to the server. When I do so, I get the following error:

> The following URL is not valid: http://myserver.domain.com/sites/mysite/Workflows/My Workflow Name/My Workflow Name.xsn

I've tried looking in the SP logs, and don't see anything relevant at the time I try to publish the form. I can make the changes to forms on my dev box that has InfoPath installed locally. But when I take a site backup and restore onto the production server, then try to make any form edits using InfoPath on my client, I get the same error.

Any thoughts on what the cause might be and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer or a workaround for this that you can add in the answer box below?

Comment: Nope, nothing yet. This hasn't been a high enough priority for me to call up and work with MS support on the issue though. Only work around we have right now is to take and SC backup, put it on a dev box with Designer installed locally, work with it there, and restore to production.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could understand the problem is [how to migrate and relink workflow to another URL/location/server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/how-to-reconnect-infopath-task-form-to-spd-workflow-after-moving-it-to-the-new-s/41551#41551)

That is there is no OOTB possibility to change publish location in Infopath form templates of types/compatibility Sharepoint List Form and WorkFlow Form and one needs to use workarounds for this, i.e. hack Infopath form template source files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the initiation form from the workflow by selecting the form and pressing 'del' key. And then try to make your changes.