# How to reconnect InfoPath task form to SPD workflow after moving it to the new Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, migration

I have Globally reusable workflow (created in SPD) in my test site collection. This WF uses custom InfoPath task form. Now I am trying to move it to the new production site collection. I've done next steps.

1. Copy my globally reusable WF (in SPD) to make it reusable (I can't save GLOBALLY reusable WF as a template).
2. Save new reusable WF (not globally reusable) as WF template and deployed it to the production environment.

And now my WF is working well, but I've missed my custom InfoPath task forms and I don't know how to connect it to my WF.

**Is there any way to reuse InfoPath task forms from my workflow after moving from test environment to production? May be I have to use another approach?**

Every suggestions are very appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

PS: I don't understand completely what is happenning behind the scenes, when I am creating custom InfoPath task forms in SPD. I googled about it, but couldn't find any good article to clarify. If you know any articles or books which could help me in my understanding of relationship between InfoPath and SharePoint 2010, it would be great if you recommend it.

PPS: SharePoint 2010.

**UPDATE 1:** It seems like InfoPath forms are missed in step 1 (I can't see forms in wsp file). If I create new reusable WF (not globally) with InfoPath forms, I can see them in the wsp file and WF deploys correctly with forms. 
It seems like the [way which Microsoft recommends for converting Globaly reusable WF to reusable WF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff358272.aspx) doesn't work well and miss InfoPath task forms.

Also I found an [unanswered question about the same problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/5be39312-88ea-4f1b-ab5b-d2c1cce965ca/) on MSDN forum.

Comment: What if you deleted the form from your computer thinking that that would do the job.. then emptied your trash bin? That is what I did and now I cannot get rid of the form on SharePoint

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update:
[The more structured and concise step-by-step description by Puhan](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/41556/8319).

---

The answer to this question is the same as answer(s) to question [Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location#comment38102_17383)

- Update:
  Though the marked as best and the most upvoted there answers proposing [the use UDCX data connection files are not applicable to Infopath Form templates of type/compatibility Sharepoint List Form and Workflow Form at all](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/21923/81104.aspx#81104). The best answers should have been describing the hacking of template's source files which are unfortunately the less voted there

That is, if you open (by clicking on) Infopath XSN form template under **Forms** workflow section which are for **Approval - Sharepoint 2010**:

- **reviewapproval_1033.xsn**
  which is published as:

  - (HTTP or HTTPS)//( **sharepoint_webapp_URL** )/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=/_catalogs/wfpub/approval%20-%20sharepoint%202010/**reviewapproval_1033.xsn**
- **reviewapproval_task_1033.xsn**
  which is published as:

  - (HTTP or HTTPS)//( **sharepoint_webapp_URL** )/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=/_catalogs/wfpub/approval%20-%20sharepoint%202010/**reviewapproval_task_1033.xsn**

they should open in **Infopath Designer 2010**. And there in backstage view, by clicking on ribbon **File** >  **Publish** you should see that publish location against **Workflow** button under:

- Publish a Sharepoint workflow form
- Update the current Sharepoint workflow form

  The form will be published to:
  (HTTP or HTTPS)//( **sharepoint_webapp_URL** )/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=/_catalogs/wfpub/approval - sharepoint 2010/reviewapproval_task_1033.xsn

[image: Workflow published location is locked]

This (published location) is locked and link cannot be edited/changed through Infopath Designer GUI when Infopath forms is in **Workflow** (or **Sharepoint List Form**) compatibility mode

You can check the type/compatibility of form by pressing **Form Options** button while having XSN form opened in **Infopath Designer 2010**

[image: Infopath form template of type Workflow Form is non-modifiable and locked]

Well, the main culprit is unmodifiable and locked (main) data connections/sources  which can checked by clicking (still having an Infopath Task Form opened) in **Infopath Designer 2010** the **Data Connections** under tab **Data**, on tibbon > choose **Main Data Connection** > "**Modify...**" button

So, you should save locally each of XSN templates under different custom name (not offered by default template.xsn)

Then open each in Infopath Designer 2010 (for example, by right-clicking the .XSN file in Windows Explorer and choosing Design) and in backstage (on ribbon **File** > **Publish** > ) click "**Export Source Files**" button and while saving, create a separate directory for each form template (originally a file with an .XSN extension).

Close Infopath Designer 2010

Open the manifest.xsf in text/XML editor. Find and replace all hyperlinks from old site URL to a new one (according your new site collection location). Save the file.

Open XSN form template again (by right-clicking on **manifest.xsf** > Design) in Infopath Designer and publish it by

- on ribbon, **File** > **Info** > **Quick Publish**

into now the new, just edited before,  site location.

You should repeat it for each Infopath form

**Update:**

Also, you might want to make sure searching your old URL through all source files of Infopath template not just one, MANIFEST.XSF, I mentioned here (also they can be in **view*.xsl**).