# Making changes to existing infopath form

Tags: infopath

I am totally new to SharePoint. I just have a question regarding SharePoint.I have modified an existing infopath template and published it to a new library. I have a submit option in the template that saves those forms in the library. If I have saved the new form, it works fine. But if I try to modify the saved document with the new template, it still points to the old template. How do I resolve this? Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Lakshmi

Comment: Lakshmi, you say you published the template to a new library. Does this mean that the old forms are in the old library?

Answer (score 2):

**In case of libraries**
when the data are stored in XML files it is necessary [to relink XML forms to used/linked in their heading reference to location of XSN form template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/11/01/relinking-forms-and-form-templates.aspx):

- **Hand-edit:**
  the href in form's XML file
- **Re-linking**
  (available only if the form template published to form but not document, library)
- **PIFix.exe tool:**
  limited to IP form template published to file share

See more details the mentioned article.

**In case of data stored in sharepoint lists** (incl. workflow forms)
it is necessary [to change URL to which a template has been published in its source files](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/41551/8319).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you published your form as content type right? Go to the list's content type settings and remove the old content type from the list - or alternatively set the default to your new content type.