# Cert expired on InfoPath form and yields an error in MOSS

Tags: 2007, infopath, document-library, certificate, expiration

I have a very particular case in SharePoint 2007 and InfoPath 2007. I am using InfoPath 2010 as the designer, deploying the InfoPath form to SharePoint 2007 with a signed certificate and some code behind. The certificate was signed for one year and has now expired. Re-signing the form with a new certificate and publishing does not fix the issue. I still get the same generic error message:

> The form cannot be opened becuase either the signature is corrupt, or
>   the certificate used to sign the form has expired or has been revoked.
>   To fix this problem, contact the form designer.

pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I yields the following error number: 1202431. Here is what I have found:

Here is what I have tried:

1. I found [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888704), that this is a bug in InfoPath form, but the workaround isn't very helpful; which I have tried many times with different certificates.
2. Deleted the InfoPath form from the list by using SharePoint Designer and publishing again with a new signed cert
3. Same as Step 2 above, except this time calling the template something different and updating the list with the new template name.

The only thing to PARTIALLY work was Step 2, which allowed me to create a new Infopath form without error, but existing InfoPath forms wouldn't open and would yield the same error.

**Any ideas on how I can sign new and exiting InfoPath forms int he Document Library and have them open using a new certificate?**

Comment: regarding step 2 above, I did just notice that even though I renamed the template when I published, the existing forms, when opened in notepad show an href with a reference to the old template. Perhaps this is the key to getting this solved.

Comment: ok another update... changing this href to point to the new template was successful in opening the new and existing form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but existing InfoPath forms wouldn't open and would yield the same
>   error

because they are linked to a (bad) template with bad (expired) certificate

So, essentially your question is [how to relink old documents to a new template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/42579)