# Copying content types along with the Infopath Form from one library to another in SharePoint 2007

Tags: infopath, content-type

I am trying to copy a Infopath Form from one library to another ( archive ) in SharePoint 2007 with all of the information available in the first library. In other words, I do not want only copy the form but also the content type columns and corresponding information. I would appreciate if you could help me on that.

Thank you.

Edit : Actually i am migrating a file from one library to another under the same site and server. To do that, I am using copy & delete action in SharePoint Designer. However, once i move the file to the new library, the content types columns are not moved with the InfoPath form. What I would like to have is copying the columns with the InfoPath form.

Answer (score 1):

This depends.

If you migrate to another server (preserving/restoring all external connections/configurations ) then then package a sharepoint site as  a WSP and then deploy it on another server.

If you want just to copy, then create a new library,  copy Infopath XML data forms files, re-publish XSN template to a new library having made a copy of XSN template file locally and [relink XML data files to a new URL of published XSN template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/42579).

**Update:**
Generally speaking your question is not question but request for googling:

- [Archive or move InfoPath forms in SharePoint](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/06/archive-move-infopath-forms-sharepoint/) , by by S.Y.M. Wong-A-Ton |
- [Migrating Infopath form libraries in Sharepoint](http://www.codistri.net/migrate-infopath-forms/) (codistri.net)
- etc.