# Submit an Old Form to a new Sharepoint

Tags: infopath

I had to start a new sharepoint for different reasons but I wanted to keep the format the same. I recreated my sharepoint list and copied a form from the old sharepoint. I updated my URL in Data connection wizard and the document will successfully publish into Sharepoint. However the information from the form no longer populates into the list columns. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to File > Publish and then removing and re-adding the columns? Maybe the CAML names of the columns in the new list are different than the old list, and therefore SharePoint can't recognize the new columns.

Comment: CAML is unnecessary for this

Comment: @user15962 Glad that I could help! Please accept my answer so that I will get credit for helping you.

Comment: +1 since it solved OP's problem (shame they didn't even up-vote, let alone mark accepted).

Answer (score 0):

I was in doubt whether to answer this question because it is not clear:

- what do you mean under starting a "new sharepoint'
  a sharepoint new site, sharepoint site collection or entire server migration?
- How have you "updated  my URL in Data connection wizard"
- Which is the type/compatibility of Infopath form template?

If you are having Infopath form template of type/compatibility of **Sharepoint List Form**, then the **main** data connection (source) is not modifiable OOTB. You can change it only through exporting the source files of XSN template > modifying dataconnection > republishing template.

See my answers to questions:

- [How to reconnect InfoPath task form to SPD workflow after moving it to the new Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/41551/8319)
- [Making changes to existing infopath form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/42579)
- [Copying content types along with the Infopath Form from one library to another in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/61607)