# Does Updating Infopath form for Library required to update the task infopath forms in WF

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have an infopath form which is deployed using stsadm.

This infopath form is published to Form Library A. This library has an apporval WF to approve the forms. The WF has a task forms which are infopath forms.

I need to make the changes to the name of the Field in Infopath which means there is a field name Manager in the form and  i need to change the name from Manager to Approver.

My question is if i change the name of the field in Infopath do i need to make any changes to the task form in WF?

it is 2007 64 bit environment with Infopath 2007.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have never worked with Infoapth 2007 but in Infopath 2010, and I do not think it is different in 2007, editing of Infopath forms requires Infopath Designer (2010).

Otherwise, you can try to change XSN template source XML files though it is unnecessarily complicated way which I had never tried without using Infopath Designer. Besides, the Infopath form template schems  of type /compatibility Workflow are locked and the results of such editing as well as packaging the changed source files back into XSN template archive are unpredictable and generally the worst approach from the limited set of available bad ones.

See also my answer to question:

- [How to reconnect InfoPath task form to SPD workflow after moving it to the new Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/how-to-reconnect-infopath-task-form-to-spd-workflow-after-moving-it-to-the-new-s)

Comment: Hi Gennady Vanin,
thanks for the reply as i am feeling its very hard to find people having sound  knowledge of Infopath. 
My question is if i make changes to the name in infopath form does it effects the WF?

Thanks

Comment: Plz open a separate question b/c it sounds ambiguous. Changes to the name of what, how, where (in Infopath Designer or in source XML files?) as well as what do you mean under "effects" (breaks, shows the changed names), etc.