# Importing a WSP template - Error, require feature {69cadbef-ac7d-494d-9d0a-39a26e008377}

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, import

I've made a back up of site to produce a template file (WSP) in SharePoint 2010 online. I have then tried to import into my development platform, which is also SP 2010 online but keep getting the error that i have a missing feature...

THe ID of that feature is 69cadbef-ac7d-494d-9d0a-39a26e008377 and I belive its the BPOSExtranetFlag Feature.

Is there a way to install this on my SP?

Cheers,

S

Comment: Stephen, I see you marked the answer with final comment "Thanks Vardhamam but i cant see this anywhere on my SP?" Does it mean that you failed or succeeded to import your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer from Sharepoint Online (Office 365) support team:

- "[The only templates that are supported by our team are the out-of-box templates that come with Office 365](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/155/p/58584/214683.aspx#214683)"

Update:
I disagree with belief of the question author that:

- "If the template is created from Office 365 SharePoint Online, you should be fine and they should work"

There are a lot of scalable issues in Sharepoint and Infopath, for example, just to mention a few:

Infopath Publishing wizard does not permit relative URLs with hard-coding initial reference

[image]

[image]

And it seems is not my own imagination. See, for example, the discussion [Data Connection relative to site](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23199/80374.aspx#80374)

The situation re is even more grave  with Infopath forms of type/compatibility Workflow and/or Sharepoint List Form, which schema is locked and unmodifiable at all, see for example, my answers to question:

- [deploy customized infopath form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43092/deploy-customized-infopath-form/43107#43107)
- [How to reconnect InfoPath task form to SPD workflow after moving it to the new Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/how-to-reconnect-infopath-task-form-to-spd-workflow-after-moving-it-to-the-new-s/41551#41551)
- etc.

And these are only some of the problems with migrating/deploying anything (through templates or with aother approaches)  containg Infopath forms to another Sahrepoint site

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I dont think this is relevent.  Both Sharepoints in my situation are Sharepoint online/365.

Comment: The reply did explicitly tell that only "out-of-the-box" Sharepoint Online/365 templates are supported but not custom made in Sharepoint Online/365. Though, you may continue to understand it in your own way, that's your right

Comment: Hey Gennday, that is my point.  It states "If the template is created from Office 365 SharePoint Online, you should be fine and they should work." My template has come from SP online and is going to SP online. So it should work.

Comment: Hello, Stephen, I disagree, see my Update

Comment: Hey Gennady, thanks for the detailed reply looks like we will have to build this from scratch again which is time consuming to say the least.  I can believe MS would not make this easier. Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Since the feature was activated when you created the template of the site, you will require the same feature activated when you create a new site from the template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you were correct.  I have now activated that feature on my target site.  I now have another request to activate.                                                     6E8F2B8D-D765-4e69-84EA-5702574C11D6 FAST Search End User Help Collection Enables FAST Search End User Help Collection Site. I cannot find this anywhere in my site features?

Comment: That is a site collection feature. It will be available on the root site on your site collection under Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site collection features.

Comment: Thanks Vardhamam but i cant see this anywhere on my SP?

Comment: Is this the same site collection from where you created the template? Also, are you sure you are checking the site collection features and not the site features?