# deploy customized infopath form

Tags: infopath, deployment

I have a SharePoint custom list with some fields. I modified the form using InfoPath. This modified form has many views, rules and logic inside. Now I would like to deploy this form to Production Server. How can I do such deployment ? Do I have to create whole list, fields again and create InfoPath form or is there any standard deployment process/method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is the same as the answers to question [Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/34600/8319), if we speak about unmodifiable and locked **Sharepoint List Form** type (according to compatibility in Form Options< Info < File, on ribbon of Infopath Designer 2010) and Main Data Source/Connection:

[image]

[image]

Though, I failed to apply any those approaches in case of a list containing lookup field(s) to other list(s):

- editing source filed fails completely for me (in case of a list with a lookup field)
- in case of using a list template as an STP file approach, created from template list looses lookup field(s) content

One of the obvious questions is the sense of **Sharepoint List Form** and how to create the Infopath forms if they cannot be deployed thereafter.
One of the possible workaround is manually laborious [engagement of CAML templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/03/26/submitting-to-a-sharepoint-list.aspx?PageIndex=30) though it is unrelated to (already existing) Sharpoint list forms...

Good luck! Share here your experience here, please!