# Site Template error message

Tags: site-template, site

I am trying to use a site template.  But, when I go in to use the template it gives me this error message:
The site Template requires that the feature {6e8f2b8d-d765-4e69-84ea-5702574c11d6} be activated in the site collection.

The template is activated.  So how do I fix this to use the template?

Comment: Is this feature id of publishing feature?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error because the feature was activated when you created the template of the site . You will require the same feature activated now to create a new site from the template . Activate the BPOSExtranetFlag Feature ({6e8f2b8d-d765-4e69-84ea-5702574c11d6} ) .

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42992/importing-a-wsp-template-error-require-feature-69cadbef-ac7d-494d-9d0a-39a26

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like feature {6e8f2b8d-d765-4e69-84ea-5702574c11d6} is not enabled on your Site Collection.  You could try using the Enable-SPFeature cmdlet in PowerShell to enable it manually.

```
Enable-SPFeature 6e8f2b8d-d765-4e69-84ea-5702574c11d6 -Url sitecollectionurl
```